# Iterating over a list from an object in Django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am trying to iterate over a list that is below an object in a Django template.
Unfortunately I am not getting anywhere.

This is the object:

```
{'Value1': [8, 5, 4, 7, 4, 5], 'Value2': [], 'Value3': []}
```

I am doing in the template something like:

```
{% for entry in data %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ entry }}</td>
    <td>{{ entry.0 }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

or

```
{% for entry in data %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ entry }}</td>
    {% for i in entry %}
    <td>{{ i }}</td>
    {% endfor %} 
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

But all I am getting is just the first letter of the key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to look for both - keys and values in dict's items:

```
{% for key, value_list in data.items %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ entry }}</td>
    {% for value in value_list %}
        <td>{{ value }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try iterating over the items in your dict, like so?

```
{% for key, value in data.items %}
```